# "Configuration system failed to initialize" error

Tags: c#, xml, app-config

I'm getting this exception when using the code:

```
var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings; //Exception here
string result = appSettings["ILFSsqlServer"] ?? "Not Found"; //trying to get to this point
```

I'm not really sure why and from previous answers to this question I think I'm doing exactly what they suggest but to no avail.

My app.config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings"
        type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <AppSettings>
    <add key="ILFSsqlServer" value="ODBC;DSN=sql server copycloas;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2010;DATABASE=ILFSView;"/>
  </AppSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your app.config you should write appSettings, lowercase A.